# By Removing vim-minimal I removed sudo

Tags: fedora, vim, sudo

I'm on Fedora 25 gnome, I rarely use vim, so I decided to remove vim minimal

```
sudo dnf remove totem-1\:3.22.0-1.fc25.x86_64 
bash: sudo: command not found...
Install package 'sudo' to provide command 'sudo'? [N/y] y

 * Waiting in queue... 
The following packages have to be installed:
 sudo-1.8.18p1-1.fc25.x86_64    Allows restricted root access for specified users
 vim-minimal-2:8.0.194-1.fc25.x86_64    A minimal version of the VIM editor
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y
```

So I was forced to reinstall it to use sudo, no big deal but why? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: I'm supposing `sudo` depends on `vim` for the `visudo` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda but `vi` is also installed and on any server in the world, they rarely install vim, `visudo` should use `vi`. I never had any server where `vim` is installed

Comment: @Kusalananda I see now what you mean, fedora made vim the default editor thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `sudo` depends on the vi package to edit the sudoers file (`visudo`), but it seems like for Fedora it's vim minimal.

You can actually change the default editor used by visudo by setting the `EDITOR` variable to another editor and exporting it.